# Not exactly directed percolation

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, random-graphs, statistical-physics, percolation

Is the following problem known/well-studies? I'm looking for references or a name that I can look up.

> I start with $N$ cell, each one divides into two cells, each one of the new cells either dies with probability $p$ or divides into two cells, and so on.
>
> - What is the probability distribution of the number of cells after $n$ generations?
> - What can be said about the critical $p$ below which the population goes extinct?
> - Are there Universal scaling laws for this extinction transition?

At first, I thought it was [directed percolation problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_percolation), but the exponential growth in the possible number of cells is not consistent with DP.

Comment: I would say that this is $N$ independent  Galton–Watson processes, where the distribution of the r.v. are concentrated on 0 and 2.

Comment: @Leandro Thank you, that is exactly what I needed to know